# Simple toupper coding in C

Tags: c, toupper

I want to make a simple toupper coding on my Laptop (windows 7). It appears that anything i wrote it only capitalize 1 word in the beginning.

Whether i use %s / %c / %[^\n]

What am I suppoused to do?

Im using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char kalimat;
    scanf ("%[^\n]",&kalimat);
    kalimat=toupper(kalimat);
    printf("%s",kalimat);
    getchar ();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `kalimat` is just a single character, it's not a string.

Comment: you should define `kalimat` as array. Alternatively a pointer and malloc enough memory for your string

Comment: [sample to fix](http://ideone.com/c2tuLd)

Answer (score 1):

You want to read a word. For this, you need an array of `char` of some pre-defined size. So change

```
char kalimat;
```

to

```
char kalimat[64]; /* Can hold 63 chars, +1 for the NUL-terminator */
```

Next, you want to scan a word. So change

```
scanf("%[^\n]",&kalimat);
```

to

```
scanf("%63s", kalimat);
```

The changes made here are

1. Usage of `%s` used to scan a word as opposed to `%c` which is used to scan a character.
2. Removing the ampersand because `%s` expects a `char*`, not a `char**` or `char(*)[64]`.
3. Using a length specifier (63, here) in order to prevent a buffer overflow.

Then, if you want to

1. Captalize the first character of the array/word, use

   ```
   kalimat[0] = toupper(kalimat[0]);
   ```

   or

   ```
   *kalimat = toupper(*kalimat);
   ```
2. Capitalize all characters in the array, use a loop calling `toupper` on each index of the array:

   ```
   int i, len; /* Declare at the start of `main` */

   for(i = 0, len = strlen(string); i < len; i++) /* Note: strlen requires `string.h` */
       kalimat[i] = toupper(kalimat[i]);
   ```

But... you might need to change

```
getchar ();
```

to

```
int c; /* Declare at the start of `main` */
while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n');
```

in order to prevent the consle from closing.

---

**Fixed code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h> /* For `strlen` */

int main()
{
    int i, len, c;
    char kalimat[64];

    scanf ("%63s", &kalimat);

    /* `*kalimat = toupper(*kalimat);` */
    /* or */
    /* `kalimat[0] = toupper(kalimat[0]);` */
    /* or */
    /* `for(i = 0, len = strlen(string); i < len; i++) 
        kalimat[i] = toupper(kalimat[i]);` */

    printf("%s", kalimat);

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n');
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The C library function :

```
int toupper(int c);
```

converts a lower case letter to its uppercase

If you want to print all letters of a string to it's upper case :

```
int i=0;
while(str[i])
{
 putchar (toupper(str[i]));
 i++;
}
```

However for capitalising a single character you could simply use:

```
 putchar (toupper(mychar));
```

The function returns uppercase if there exists one or returns the same character sent to it.

In C you could store a string :

```
 char *string1="Elvis";
 char string2[]="Presley";
 char string3[4]="King";
```